# Why does invoking "normal!" in insert mode cause error "Not allowed here"?

Tags: vimscript

New to vimscript.  I am trying to invoke a function in insert-mode.  The function is a bit complicated, but I am stuck at running "normal!".

Here is the mapping:

```
inoremap <buffer> <expr> <c-o> Tmp2()
nnoremap <buffer> <c-o> :call Tmp2()<cr>
```

Here is a very simple func that demonstrates my problem

```
function! Tmp2()
     normal! yiW
     echom @@
     return @@
endfunction
```

When I run the command in normal mode, it works fine.  When I am in insert mode I get:

```
Line 1:
E523: Not allowed here
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In `:help <expr>`, we find:

```
Be very careful about side effects!  The expression is evaluated while
obtaining characters, you may very well make the command dysfunctional.
For this reason the following is blocked:
- Changing the buffer text |textlock|.
- Editing another buffer.
- The |:normal| command.
- Moving the cursor is allowed, but it is restored afterwards.
If you want the mapping to do any of these let the returned characters do
that.
```

As filbranden points out in the comments, a method that works well here is

```
inoremap <buffer> <C-o> <C-r>=Tmp2()<CR>
```

Comment: Great answer! It would be nice to add that `inoremap <buffer> <c-o> <C-R>=Tmp2()<CR>` actually works for cases such as this one... Since the side effect in that case is happening during the execution of the macro, and not evaluation...

Comment: That works! Thx! What is the role of <C-R> in that expression?

Comment: @hba see `:help <C-r>`; it's used to insert the value of a register (in this case, the expression register)

Comment: @hba See [`:help i_CTRL-R`](https://vimhelp.org/insert.txt.html#i_CTRL-R). You might also want to read on the expression register, under [`:help "=`](https://vimhelp.org/change.txt.html#quote%3D).

Comment: Thank you both.  I just started with vimscript, and I find it very confusing :-)